# Difference between current datetime and DateTimeField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-3.0

I'm been trying to get the difference between a DateTimeField and the current datetime

Below is how I currently query objects:

```
comment = Comment.objects.filter(ticket=ticket)
```

The above query returns:

- comment
- user
- date_added

I would like to compute the time that has passed since the comment was posted (like this -> 
[image: screenshot])

I tried the code below but I'm getting the following:

> AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'split'

```
comment = Comment.objects.filter(ticket=ticket).annotate(duration=Func(F(datetime.datetime.now()) - F('comment_date_added'),
                                                                   function='age'))
```

I'm thinking of extracting the date values as showing in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/ and handle the calculation of the time difference on the frontend but I was wondering if I missed something or if there are better ways to solve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clearly missed/forgot about [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

My issue has been resolved by doing the following on the template:

```
{% for item in comment %}
    Posted {{ item.comment_date_added|timesince }} ago
{% endfor %}
```